# Vue.js throwing inexplicable syntax error for Blackberry browser 10.3

Tags: webpack, vue.js, blackberry-10

I'm using `Vue.js` to build a site and I'm getting the following error in Blackberry Browser 10.3:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('   app.a3c4ee08427b9dd5e351.js:268`

And when I view the line that's referenced in the error in the compiled `app.a3c4ee08427b9dd5e351.js` file I see the following:

```
/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = ({
    name: 'app-header',
    components: {},
    data: function () {
        return {};
    },
    mounted() {}, <-- THIS IS LINE 268 REFERENCED IN THE ERROR
    methods: {}
});
```

I'm using the "Single-File Template" method and this is what the above block looks like uncompiled in my source:

```
<script>

    export default {
        name: 'app-header',
        components : {},
        data : function() {
            return {}
        },
        mounted() {

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.nav-link').on('click', function() {
                    $(document).stop().animate({
                        scrollTop : 0
                    }, 444);
                });

            });

        }
    }

</script>
```

So the block throwing the error is missing the contents of the `mounted()` function. BUT, there's a second block further down in the compiled file that *does* have the contents of the `mounted()` function intact for the `app-header` component:

```
/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = ({
    name: 'app-header',
    components: {},
    data: function () {
        return {};
    },
    mounted() {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('.nav-link').on('click', function () {
                $(document).stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 444);
            });

        });
    }
});
```

The error itself seems to be saying that I've got an errant `(` somewhere, but I've combed over it 1000 times and can't seem to find where this is happening.

Also, this works perfectly well in all other browsers.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this for `BB Browser 10.3`?

Note: The client owns a Blackberry, which is why we're targeting a device that only 5 or 6 people on the planet actually use.

Comment: Did you try `mounted: function(){...}`?

Comment: @Bert, I did and got the same result. Might be worth trying again though.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a valid JS object for ES3. I'm kind of surprised it works on any devices.

Comment: @Nostalg.io, what are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to how the `mounted()` function property is defined, but I guess that is valid in ES6. You'll have to forgive me, I learned JavaScript back before jQuery.